# Overcoming Subquery returned more that 1 value

Tags: sql-server

This context might not be helpful, but in case it is: I am working with placement records for clients in foster care. They change if the client leaves the home for respite or if their rate changes or if they change foster parents or if they change subprogram or for a few other reasons as well. I am trying to identify the earliest placement start date which has the same foster parent, rate, and subprogram as the current one (and is not respite).

I've created a view that has the max placement that does not have status of RSPT. I am now trying to find the earliest they have been in that placement with the following code:

```
SELECT    MAX(PL.[PLCMNT ST DT]) AS MaxStDt, 
          PL.ProgID
FROM      dbo.PlacementLog AS PL 

          INNER JOIN dbo.ProgramLog AS PR ON 
          PL.ProgID = PR.[PROGRAM KEY]

WHERE     (PR.[PROGRAM CODE] = 29) AND 
          (PL.PlcmntStatus <> N'RSPT') AND 
          (PL.[PLCMNT ST DT] <
                               (SELECT     MaxStartDate
                                FROM       dbo.FcMaxNonRespPlcmntS2 AS FCM
                                WHERE      (ProgID = PL.ProgID) AND 
                                           (RCode = PL.[RATE CODE]) AND 
                                           (FosFamID = PL.FosFamID) AND 
                                           (SubProg = PL.SubProg)))
GROUP BY PL.ProgID, 
         PL.SubProg, 
         PL.[RATE CODE], 
         PL.FosFamID
```

I am getting the Subquery Returned More than 1 value. This is not permitted... error. Any insight in what I"m doing wrong? Also, is there a way to add to this code a case when that would say if an early placement doesn't exist, the list the max placement from FcMaxNonRespPlcmntS2?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT     MAX(PL.[PLCMNT ST DT]) AS MaxStDt, PL.ProgID
FROM         dbo.PlacementLog AS PL INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ProgramLog AS PR ON PL.ProgID = PR.[PROGRAM KEY]
WHERE     (PR.[PROGRAM CODE] = 29) AND (PL.PlcmntStatus <> N'RSPT') AND (PL.[PLCMNT ST DT] <
                          (SELECT     TOP 1 MaxStartDate
                            FROM          dbo.FcMaxNonRespPlcmntS2 AS FCM
                            WHERE      (ProgID = PL.ProgID) AND (RCode = PL.[RATE CODE]) AND (FosFamID = PL.FosFamID) AND (SubProg = PL.SubProg)
                            ORDER BY MaxStartDate DESC))
GROUP BY PL.ProgID, PL.SubProg, PL.[RATE CODE], PL.FosFamID
```